# locally stored Images are not showing in XSL Output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using following xsl code to display image on html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <img src="http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif"  alt="MM"/>
    <img src="c:\view.png" alt=""/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am seeing image on html only for the 1st one, i.e, image from http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif but the image from 2nd one (from "C:\view.png") is not getting displayed.

its the same behaviour for the images which are stored in the folder where xml is located.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error console of your browser displaying the result of the XSLT transformation, it is probably showing you an error or warning message that the local file system access is not allowed.

Or try whether using a URI instead of a file path, i.e. `<img src="file:///C:/view.png"/>` improves things.

Comment: It worked with <img src="file:///C:/view.png"/>. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: above fix works when we specify absolute path along with "file:///", but when we use relative path like "file:///./icon/view.png", it wont work. Required Icons are located in subfolder "icons" of xml located folder. For. ex. xml folder location is "C:\1\2\3\4\result.xml" and icons are located at "C:\1\2\3\4\icons". How to specify relative path to access images under icons folder

Comment: If you open an XML document in `C:\1\2\3\4` and want to refer to images in the subdirectory `C:\1\2\3\4\icons` then simply use `<img src="icons/img1.png"/>` (note the foward slash). If you want to go up one directory use `<img src="../img2.png"/>`.